# How does Dropwizard works?

Tags: dropwizard

For a very simple program such as this:

```
package com.example.helloworld;

import com.yammer.dropwizard.Service;
import com.yammer.dropwizard.config.Bootstrap;
import com.yammer.dropwizard.config.Environment;

public class HelloWorldService extends Service<HelloWorldConfiguration> {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new HelloWorldService().run(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(Bootstrap<HelloWorldConfiguration> bootstrap) {
        bootstrap.setName("hello-world");
    }

    @Override
    public void run(HelloWorldConfiguration configuration,
                    Environment environment) {
        // nothing to do yet
    }

}
```

Does anyone knows the steps (20k views from above the sea is fine) how Dropwizard takes this in and eventually generating a jar ?

The code example was taken from their getting started guide.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you want to know how to build a executable jar:
You can use Maven as described here:

http://www.dropwizard.io/0.7.1/docs/getting-started.html#setting-up-maven

If this does not answer your question please refine your question.